# firebase auth share session/token between microservices

Tags: firebase, express, authentication, firebase-authentication, next.js

I working with firebase auth and I'm a bit confused on how to manage the authentication between different apps, in particular nextjs (main site, that use express too) api and react app (is a kind of dashboard). After reading a bit of documentation what I did (but I'm not sure is the right way) is to get the idToken on the main site with the client side library:

```
firebase
  .auth()
  .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(() => {
    const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken();
    currentUser.then(idToken => {
      return axios.post("/auth/login", { idToken });
    });
  });
```

and make a request to nextjs/express to create the cookie sessions:

```
firebase
  .auth()
  .createSessionCookie(idToken, { expiresIn })
  .then(
    sessionCookie => {
      res.cookie("session", sessionCookie, {
        maxAge: expiresIn,
        httpOnly: true
      });
      return res.end(JSON.stringify({ status: "success" }));
    },
    error => res.status(401).send(error)
  );
```

then when I need to send a request to the api I'll pass the idtoken saved in the cookie and I verify the token in a middleware

```
const userInfo = await firebase.auth().verifySessionCookie(authToken);
```

I'm not implemented the react app yet but I think in that I'll just use the clientside library to do everything....My main doubt is the authentication between the nextjs/express and the api, I'm not sure if usin the sessioncookie is the right choise...do I need to send just the tokenId instead of the session cookie? do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Check this link, it might be helpful: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies @francesco.venica

Comment: already read it! my only doubt is if it't correct to use the session token like the idtoken to communicate with other microservices, after reading around and after checking the token I saw that is more or less the same of the idtoken so I'm using the session token like an idtoken